# Rails - HTTParty How to access params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

So i'm using a pretty standard setup to test HTTParty out:

```
  def index

     @hotels = HTTParty.get('https://api-v3.igdb.com/games/',
        :headers =>{"Content-Type" => "application/json", "user-key" => "super_secret_key"},
        :query => {:fields => "name",  :limit =>  "20"})
  end
```

this works. I get 20 items back.

I iterate through them in the view like so:

```
<% @hotels.each do |game| %>
    <p>game name is:<%= game.to_query %> </p>
<% end %>
```

which results on the html file inside the browser to the following: 
(just 1 example taken)

> game name is:id=69359&name=Sunken+Secrets

Obviously, i would like to render the name and the id like normal params, just like normally in Rails: <=% game.name %> for example

//Update:

When i run byebug, i get the following result back for @hotels

```
>     <HTTParty::Response:0x7ff207cd0270 parsed_response=[{"id"=>69359, "name"=>"Sunken Secrets"}, {"id"=>69530, "name"=>"Dai Senryaku VII:
> Modern Military Tactics"}, {"id"=>81332, "name"=>"Stick Fighter II"},
> {"id"=>50649, "name"=>"Who Wants to be a Millionaire: 1st Edition"},
> {"id"=>22618, "name"=>"Battleground 7: Bull Run"}, {"id"=>104945,
> "name"=>"Woodpunk"}, {"id"=>91579, "name"=>"Racing Live"},
> {"id"=>22636, "name"=>"Call of Duty: Black Ops - Annihilation"},
> {"id"=>88041, "name"=>"Highway Wars"}, {"id"=>31258,
> "name"=>"Slymes"}, {"id"=>90512, "name"=>"Asian Riddles 4"},
> {"id"=>105842, "name"=>"Robots Vs Zombies: Transform To Race And
> Fight"}, {"id"=>85450, "name"=>"Transformers Prime: The Game"},
> {"id"=>104748, "name"=>"Space station - build your own ISS"},
> {"id"=>111593, "name"=>"Oppai Puzzle"}, {"id"=>42610,
> "name"=>"Hebereke's Popoon"}, {"id"=>105254, "name"=>"Codenames"},
> {"id"=>91756, "name"=>"Aban Hawkins & the 1000 SPIKES"}, {"id"=>2057,
> "name"=>"Out Run 2019"}, {"id"=>93987, "name"=>"Pi Story"}],
> @response=#<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>,
> @headers={"date"=>["Wed, 25 Dec 2019 18:04:48 GMT"],
> "content-type"=>["application/json;charset=utf-8"],
> "content-length"=>["1259"], "connection"=>["close"],
> "set-cookie"=>["__cfduid=de604d7fc295fb415e047830a8ce304281577297088;
> expires=Fri, 24-Jan-20 18:04:48 GMT; path=/; domain=.igdb.com;
> HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax"], "x-count"=>["124726"], "via"=>["1.1 vegur"],
> "cf-cache-status"=>["DYNAMIC"],
> "strict-transport-security"=>["max-age=15552000; preload"],
> "x-content-type-options"=>["nosniff"], "expect-ct"=>["max-age=604800,
> report-uri=\"https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct\""], "server"=>["cloudflare"], "cf-ray"=>["54acbd52ae077cb2-MUC"]}>
```

Any ideas if there is way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you convert it to a query?

Comment: I don't. I just want to render the data. Removing to_query results in the same problem.

Comment: You call “to_query”. Did you inspect the returned data?

Comment: I've updated the post and added the byebug log. Maybe this might help?

Comment: So it’s in “parsed_response” then?

Comment: Answer below works! Thanks for your input & taking your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect HTTParty to return a hash. Therefore IMO this should work:

```
<% @hotels.each do |game| %>
    <p>game name is: <%= game['name'] %> </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your comment! I've tried this out already, but this just returns nil. I've updated the OP and added the byebug response. If you have any more ideas what could cause this i would appreciate it!

Comment: It returns a hash with stringified keys. My fault, I updated my answer. Please try again.

Comment: More like mine, should have had added the byebug log in the first place. Thank you! It finally works! Thanks for taking your time!